# Angular 6: Changing Content of Component Based on URL Param, Content Change Lags

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my ngOnInit I'm subscribed to a service, mapping out an object and rendering said object in my template.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.privateService.someService(this.id)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.mapRes = response;
        }
      )
  }
```

When the id in the url param changes, I am changing the data in my template based on the new Id. I am also using rxjs take() operator to make the async operation easier and less laggy. But, the lag continues. It's taking almost a second from the time I am changing the url param to the template re-rendering with the new data.

```
ngDoCheck() {
   let tempId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if(this.id === tempId) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      this.privateService.someService(this.id)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.mapRes = response;
        }
      )
      this.id = tempId;
    }
  }
```

I'm thinking this lag is happening because I am still subscribed to someService in my ngOnIt and then I am re-subbing to the service in the ngDoCheck() hook.

How can I unsunscribe to the service without using the component being destroyed (which is the case here) so that I can re-render the same component but with different data?

edit:
I'm wondering if my issue is the template change changing the actual dom and that's the source of lag instead of the stream? Because after the ngDoCheck is fired, I am getting only 1 object back using the take() operator so the stream theoretically stops

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the re-subscribing in ngDoCheck could create many subscriptions and depending on how many instances of the component there on the screen at one time, this problem would multiply. But the real problem is your trying to handle a service call every time ngDoCheck fires. If you put a console.count in that callback I willing to bet you see that service call kick off many requests. Instead, on init you will want to subscribe to the changes of the route via subscribing to route.params or route.paramsMap or router.events. since paramsMap is an asynchronous Observable it is probably moving on to your `else` block right away and firing off the request on every doCheck.

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback. route.params.subcribe doesn't change anything in terms of lag. That was the first solution I implemented before trying the ngDoCheck hook, but no luck in terms of reducing lag.

Comment: I'm wondering if my issue is the template change changing the actual dom and that's the source of lag instead of the stream? Becuase after the ngDoCheck is fired, I am getting only 1 object back using the take() operator so the stream theoretically stops